# How to send a signature from a React App to a Node JS Server with ethereum-cryptography?

Tags: javascript, serialization, cryptography, ethereum, js-ethereum-cryptography

I'm doing an exercise from Alchemy where I need to sign a transaction before sending it to the server. And then validate the transaction on the server side. I'm using a script to which I input a private key and message to generate the signature use here:

Note I need to convert the `signMessage` to `String`, otherwise I get a `TypeError: Do not know how to serialize a BigInt`:

```js
  async function transfer(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    const signMessage = {
      r: 36691152806955910003274360488470766136656266395316605280087404244279825225745n,
      s: 25775843654993118241418850103739194190473898130155752009759534141754021856163n,
      recovery: 0,
    };

    try {
      const {
        data: { balance },
      } = await server.post(`send`, {
        signature: signMessage.toString(),
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
      alert(ex.response.data.message);
    }
  }
```

Then I'm using this code on the server side, but it doesn't work. I cannot convert the `String` back to `BigInt` due to err `SyntaxError: Cannot convert [object Object] to a BigIn`:

```js
app.post("/send", (req, res) => {
  // TODO: get a signature from the client-side app
  // recover the public address from the signature

  const { signature } = req.body;

  // Convert the strings back to BigInt and Buffer
  const signatureBigInt = BigInt(signature);
  console.log({ signatureBigInt });

  res.send("testing");
  
});
```

I've tried different things and convertion types but I think I'm missing something or I'm fundamentally wrong about what I'm doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From mdn doc:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_convert_x_to_BigInt)

> When using the BigInt() function to convert a value to a BigInt, the
> value would first be converted to a primitive. Then, if it's not one
> of BigInt, string, number, and boolean, the error is thrown.

Looks like only `BigInt, string, number, and boolean` types can be converted.

Instead of stringifying the complete object, you should be stringifying the value of object key that you want to pass

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in the frontend, which is [the MDN recommendation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt#use_within_json) for serialising `BigInt`:

```
BigInt.prototype.toJSON = function() { return this.toString() }
```

And then in the backend, use this code to deserialise and create a `Signature` instance:

```
const { transaction, signature } = req.body;
const { sender, recipient, amount } = transaction;
const { r, s, recovery } = signature;

const sig = new secp256k1.Signature(BigInt(r), BigInt(s), recovery);
```

From the [Upgrading section](https://github.com/ethereum/js-ethereum-cryptography#upgrading) of [js-ethereum-cryptography](/questions/tagged/js-ethereum-cryptography), note that:

> Upgrading from 1.0 to 2.0:
>
> 1. `secp256k1` module was changed massively:
>    before, it was using [noble-secp256k1 1.7](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-secp256k1);
>    now it uses safer [noble-curves](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-curves). Please refer
>    to [upgrading section from curves README](https://github.com/paulmillr/noble-curves#upgrading).
>    Main changes to keep in mind: a) `sign` now returns `Signature` instance
>    b) `recoverPublicKey` got moved onto a `Signature` instance.